# [cocos2d-x]I have an error when I try to run 'python android-build.py -p 19 cpp-tests' in Windows 10

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x

When i try to run the command `python android build -p cpp-tests`, i'm getting an error as in the image:

[image]

Before this, I had another error message about Android SDK Tools version compatiblity. So, I just replaced sdk version form 26.0.0 to 25.2.3 and it worked.
But for this i'm not getting any solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include <unistd.h>` header is missing in `ProcessCpuTracker.cpp` file for NDK v15, there is an [issue](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/17940) reported for the same.

Either you downgrade NDK to previous version r14 or apply patch by yourself.

[Patch](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/17943) will be included in official release of 3.16.