# Can't compile android cocos2d file --Android-Studio

Tags: javascript, android, c++, android-studio, cocos2d-x

Getting some error even for sample cocos2d helloworld file.

```
Android NDK: android-13 is unsupported. Using minimum supported version android-14.    
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dxandroid_static <= ProcessCpuTracker.cpp
/home/user/Documents/cocos2d-x-3.15.1/game/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.cpp: In function 'std::vector<_CpuInfo> readProcStat()':
/home/user/Documents/cocos2d-x-3.15.1/game/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.cpp:69:54: error: 'read' was not declared in this scope
     const int len = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
                                                      ^
/home/user/Documents/cocos2d-x-3.15.1/game/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.cpp:70:13: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
     close(fd);
```

how to solve?

Comment: It seems that if you want peace with cocos, use what the devs are using NDK r13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Android NDK: android-13 is unsupported. Using minimum supported
>   version android-14.

Add `APP_PLATFORM := android-14` in `Application.mk` file

If you do not have that line then version of your SDK is taken from `project.properties` files.

---

`#include <unistd.h>` header is missing in `ProcessCpuTracker.cpp` file for NDK v15

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735811/3445320) answer for more detail.

Comment: Thanks.. whole day searched for solution but at last your solution worked perfectly ...