# Error occur at compiling the Cocos 2d-x project in android Studio

Tags: compiler-errors, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

[Cocos 2d-x-3.15.1 Error in android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPf7i.png)

Error occur at the time of compiling the new project in android studio

[image]

**EDIT**

I've new error in cocos2dxXXXXXX file, added screenshot below :

[image]

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan I used the NDK r10e  and Cocos 2d-x-3.10!!

Comment: please show header import of `ProcessCpuTracker.cpp` file

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Aryan Its work but now get the error in Android Studio related JAR File

Comment: show complete error log instead of piece of snapshot ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan i send u the picture of errors which comes in android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include <unistd.h>` header is missing in `ProcessCpuTracker.cpp` file for NDK v15

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735811/3445320) answer for more detail.

---

**EDIT**

`Cocos2dxDownloader.java` uses [Apache HTTP Client](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) which is removed in `Android 6.0`.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/15878) for this issue so you can use latest version or apply patch by yourself :

1. Add [android-async-http-1.4.9.jar](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/platform/android/java/libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar) inside `cocos/platform/android/java/libs/` folder
2. Minor [changes](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/15878/files#diff-059062aee2bc965a2e8dea8634faebef) (import statement) in `Cocos2dxDownloader.java` file

Comment: Shall I import the same or want to do some changes in that ( import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
         import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicHeader;) Because after changes also its showing same error and copying the same import still its showing error!! I don't understand it!!!

Comment: @KunalPitale copy `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` file into into your project folder at location:
`[YOUR COCOS STUDIO PROJECT PATH]\proj.android\libs`

Comment: @KunalPitale why didn't you update to latest version ? for more detail, take a look of this [thread](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cant-compile-to-android/26874)

Comment: I updated on latest version but its taking problem in compiling in the command prompt . So i used the older version of cocos 2d-x-3.10. But i have Cocos 2d-x-3.15.1, NDK r15, apache ant 1.10.1.

Comment: downgrading is not a solution so find your error in latest version and resolve, what is compiling error may be of `ProcessCpuTracker.cpp` ? or anything else ?

Comment: I updated the image of recent errors which comes in cocos 2d-x-3.15.1 in android studio

Comment: question already having two edit so create new question instead of editing this one(stack overflow rules and regulations) also please add error log in text format not in image/screenshot

Comment: Sorry but stack over flow not giving me permission to ask the question right now @AbhishekAryan

Comment: I generated the new question. Please check it!! Thank you!!